# Angular Error: [ng:areq]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I've checked other solution regarding the error Error: [ng:areq], most are stating the reason to be missing file function, duplication of variable or overriding the module. My controller.js code is as below and it doesn't seem to have any of those problems.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});

    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller:'ServiceController'
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/servicess/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'services.html',
        controller: 'ServicesController'
    }); 
}]);
app.controller('ServiceController', function($scope,$http){
    $scope.description='Users Details';

    $scope.add = function(){
        $http.post('/users', $scope.user)
        .success($scope.people);
    };
    $scope.people = function(){
        $http.get('/users')
        .success($scope.renderUser);
    };
    $scope.renderUser = function(response){
        $scope.users = response;
    };
        $scope.remove = function(id){
        $http.delete('/users/'+id).success($scope.people);
    };

    $scope.people();
});

app.controller('ServicesController', function($scope,$http,$routeParams,$location){
    $http.get('/servicess/'+$routeParams.id)
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.personal=data;
    });
    $scope.update = function(id){
        $http.put('/servicess/'+id,$scope.personal)
        .success(console.log('Error: [ng:areq]'));
    };
});
```

The error always arises during the $scope.update function in the success callback

```
$scope.update = function(id){
      $http.put('/servicess/'+id,$scope.personal)
      .success(console.log('Error: [ng:areq]'));
};
```

If the success callback is empty, there will be no error. Is there something that I've done wrong here or missing some syntax or statement?

Comment: I don't get it. Are you really passing `console.log` as parameter to `success`? Besides that I can see that you are overwriting your `ServicesController`-

Comment: @EricMartinez, Hi, console.log is just to test. The main purpose is actually to redirect it back to the homepage which i did it with $location.path('/home') previously, it actually works but that error [ng:areq] is still appearing.

Comment: If you would notice, the controller has slight of a different name, ServicesController and ServiceController, one without a letter 's'

Comment: Yes, you're right about that. Although I'm still confused. I know console.log is just to test, but why are you passing it as a parameter? Change it to `.success(function() { console.log('PUT successful'); });`. You're printing that error message by yourself.

Comment: You made a lot of sense here now. Yes, I should put it into a function! Didn't have thought of that. Thanks @EricMartinez ! Maybe you could post your answer so i can accept it :)

Comment: There it is. I'm glad I could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, I'm posting it as an answer

You are passing `console.log` as a parameter to `success`, instead do this

```
$scope.update = function(id){
  $http.put('/servicess/'+id,$scope.personal)
  .success(function() {
     console.log("PUT successful");
  });
};
```